# What causes those performance breaking points with GLSL shaders?

Tags: performance, opengl, glsl, shader

Being new to GLSL shaders, I noticed on my old netbook that adding a single more line to a perfectly running shader could suddenly multiply the execution time by thousands.

For example this fragment shader runs instantly while `limit`'s value is 32 or below, and takes 10 seconds to run once `limit`'s value is 33 :

```
int main()
{
    float limit=33.;//runs instantly if =32.
    float useless=0.5;
    for(float i=0.;i<limit;i++) useless=useless*useless;
    gl_FragColor=useless*vec4(1.,1.,1.,1.);
}
```

What confuses me as well is that adding one or more `useless` self-multiplications *out* of the 32 turns loop does not cause that sharp time increasing.

Here is an example without a for loop. It runs within a millisecond on my computer with 6 `sin` computations, and adding the seventh one suddenly makes the program take about 500ms to run :

```
int main()
{
    float useless=gl_FragCoord.x;
    useless=sin(useless);
    useless=sin(useless);
    useless=sin(useless);
    useless=sin(useless);
    useless=sin(useless);
    useless=sin(useless);
    useless=sin(useless);//the straw that breaks the shader's back
    gl_FragColor=useless*vec4(1.,1.,1.,1.);
}
```

On a less outdated computer I own, the compilation time becomes too big before I can find such a breaking point.

On my netbook, I'd expect the running times to increase continuously as I add operations.

I'd like to know what causes those sudden leaps and consequently if it's a problem I should adress, planning to target the reasonably widest Steam audience. If useful, here is the netbook I'm doing my tests on http://support.hp.com/ch-fr/document/c01949780 and its chipset http://ark.intel.com/products/36549/Intel-82945GSE-Graphics-and-Memory-Controller

Also I don't know if it matters but I'm using SFML to run shaders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

according to [intel](http://www.intel.com/products/chipsets/gma950/index.htm?wapkw=(gma%20950)), the GMA 950 supports shader model 2 in hardware, and shader model 3 in software. According to [microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/bb509655(v=vs.85).aspx), shader model 2 has a rather harsh limit on instruction count (64 ALU and 32 tex instructions).

my guess would be that, when having more than this instruction count, the intel driver decides to do shading in software, which would match the abysmal performance you're seeing.

the sin function might expand to multiple instructions. the loop likely gets unrolled, resulting in a higher instruction count with a higher limit. why adding the 33th multiplication outside the loop does not trigger this i don't know.

to decide whether you should fix this, i can recommend the [unity hardware stats](http://hwstats.unity3d.com/pc/gpu.html) and [steam hardware survey](http://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey). in short i'd say that the shader model 2 is nothing you need to support :)